Migrating to FCMv1, getting The JSON value could not be converted to Microsoft.NotificationHubs.Contracts.LegacyModels.NotificationPlatform
Im trying to execute an client installation to our Azure Notification hub but getting the following error when testing through postman:
400
    The provided request body is invalid. Error: The JSON value could not be converted to Microsoft.NotificationHubs.Contracts.LegacyModels.NotificationPlatform. Path: $.platform | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 19.. TrackingId:1cb814c2-d1b3-4432-90eb-950285714493,TimeStamp:11/25/2024 8:29:13 AM +00:00

This is my PUT statement:
https://mypushnotification.servicebus.windows.net/myproduction/installations/aaaaZGYwMTY1MGUxZTUxYg?api-version=2020-06
Here is the JSON Payload:
{
  "installationId": "aaaaZGYwMTY1MGUxZTUxYg",
  "platform": "fcm",
  "pushChannel": "aaaaaa-:aaaaa-yy0JUZxonoeRENh7WdvHsaa4ynOH4CRJC-NU0LMBTrrn9IoEJDXNa2e0aGr8yb3qszNPGxkoRk8",
  "tags": ["CompanyTag", "ContactID:123"],
  "expirationTime": "2025-01-25T08:23:03.3942916Z"
}

It seems to authorize correctly but no idea why it throws back the error. This all has come about trying to migrate from GCM to FCMv1. Any ideas?

Are you following any Doc?
